# How to create a virtual router with hyper v?

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I am using the Hyper V service on a Windows Server 2008 r2 (core installation). The Hyper V manager runs on a Windows 7 machine. My question is: is it possible to create a virtual router with Hyper V ? And if it's possible how do i install/create the virtual router. I would like to route between two local networks, so i don't need a connection to the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Not by Hyper-V itself, but you can do that using the RRAS server role.
Here's a tutorial: http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles-tutorials/windows-server-2008/Using-Windows-Server-NAT-Router.html

The tutorial is GUI-based, so use mmc from another machine to do that remotely.

Answer (score 1):

That's right Routing and Remote Access Service.

Need to be careful while selecting Network Card.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/jhoward/2008/06/17/hyper-v-what-are-the-uses-for-different-types-of-virtual-networks/